# Trouble with Swift's `reduce` syntax

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I consistently have trouble with the `reduce` syntax in swift. `map` and `filter` never trip me up, but `reduce` does, every time. Here's what I've tried this time, and none of them go:

```
let count = items.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.selected ? 1 : 0 }
let count = items.reduce(Int(0), combine: { return $0 + $1.selected ? 1 : 0 })
let count = items.reduce(Int(0), combine: { sum, item in return sum + item.selected ? 1 : 0 })
```

You can assume each `item` is an object with a `selected` boolean property. This is really simple and I feel my intent is clear, but the compiler doesn't have very helpful feedback: `Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '((Int), combine: (_, _) -> _)'`

How do I fix the syntax?

Answer (score 4):

This is a simple operator precedence issue, obfuscated by the compiler warning about closure signature.

The fix:

```
let count = items.reduce(0) { $0 + ($1.selected ? 1 : 0) }
```

The add operator has higher priority than the ternary, so the add happens first. Then it tries to evaluate the conditional, in this order:

```
let count = items.reduce(0) { ($0 + $1.selected) ? 1 : 0 }
```

To my  mind this should either:

- Compile, since it's returning an Int out of every iteration of reduce
- Yell, since it's adding an Int to a Bool (not yell about reduce closure signature)

...but hey, it does neither. The long term fix for me is to write closure statements in outer scope until the syntax is nailed down and then copy them in.